# automating the setting of the Java option Xmx

Tags: java, bash

When I create a cloud server instance, manually via a browser, I have to select the memory available. This information is available to the server instance operating system, which in my case is, Ubuntu. On a machine with a GUI, you can see the value displayed in `System Settings > Details`. In a cloud server without a GUI it ought to be available, somehow, theoretically.

The server will only ever perform one thing, that is, run a certain Java program, so it might as well use all the physical memory.

How can I get this value into a bash script so that I can have the Java `-Xmx` option set automatically?

Edit: When deploying to a new server instance, I upload a `run.sh` script (along with everything else such as .JAR files) that will be used on the server. That `run.sh` script should use an Xmx value that is the physical memory of the machine and that value should be automatically determined.

Comment: You can set _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable. so it will be picked by all java process.

Comment: do you run it as web server like tomcat, or as a standalone app?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tomcat. It's just a Java program that I need to run.

Comment: Karthikeyan, if I understand you correctly, your solution would require the automation of JAVA_OPTIONS instead of Xmx. In which case it's not a fundamental solution.

Comment: Could you try, `free | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}'` to get the amount of free memory. you can set the JAVA_OPTIONS based on the value of this command

Comment: Viswanath, that seems to output something less than the amount of physical memory but it's a good start. Perhaps $2 instead of $4 is the physical.

Comment: PHYSICALMEGA=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}'` Where the part after PHYSICALMEGA= is enclosed in backticks.

Comment: Then of course Xmx="$PHYSICALMEGA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Viswanath Lekshmanan...

In the `run.sh` script add the following.

```
PHYSICALMEGA=`free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Note the backticks around the value assigned to PHYSICALMEGA. In bash the backtick enclosed contents are evaluated by bash.

The same script can invoke Java in a manner similar to this...

```
java Xmx="$PHYSICALMEGA" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a unix command to get the memory, right?

try this on a sh script:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
```

or

```
$ less /proc/meminfo
```

or

```
$ more /proc/meminfo
```

or

```
$ egrep --color 'Mem|Cache|Swap' /proc/meminfo
```

it can help you!

font: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/

Answer (score 0):

In order to find free memory use `free` command. Use `-m` option to see results in MB. Then take from the second column 4th value, which is actual free memory at the moment:

```
 free -m | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```